# Connecting to Cisco AnyConnect VPN without stored certificate or shared secret

Tags: macos, vpn

Many people have discussed configuring the OS X built-in VPN client to connect to Cisco VPNs in place of the AnyConnect client. However, all discussion focuses on copying critical config information (shared secret or certificate, in particular) from a PCF or Profile.xml file included in a site-specific AnyConnect installer.

The AnyConnect installer where I am now (version 4.2.01035) seems not to deploy any profile information. `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile` contains only `AnyConnectProfile.xsd` (a standard schema definition, not anything specific to this configuration). There’s no sign of any profile XML or PCF files that I can find in `/opt/cisco`, `/Library`,  or `$HOME/Library`.

This matches the UI experience: there don’t seem to be any preconfigured profiles. Instead, on first launch I just get a blank VPN field in which I simply enter a hostname by hand (in this case, `ucbvpn.berkeley.edu`) and hit connect. This gives a login prompt including a group selection dropdown, and username and password fields. Simply entering a username and password initiates the connection in the mode specified by the given “group,” and everything works fine.

I cannot, however, figure out how this configuration can be fully transferred to the OS X native VPN client. Transferring a chosen group name from the list seemingly auto-discovered by the AnyConnect client, but the OS X VPN configuration seems to also require explicitly entering either a shared secret or a certificate.

My best guess is that the Cisco client is operating in a perhaps new mode where it can negotiate directly with the server to auto-discover any necessary configuration information, and that it’s not stored on disk anywhere. Does anyone have any experience with a setup like this, or have any suggestions of what else to try?

Comment: Unfortunately I also can't find configuration file. It really seems like the client is just fetching the information from the server. Maybe it's somehow possible to sniff the traffic? Do you have any news on this?

Comment: There are two POST requests when connecting to the vpn server. The first contains the information for the shown form, the second one after submitting that form. It creates a session-[id|token], but I don't see any VPN configuration files/information in there :/

Comment: Any interesting updates?

Comment: In my case, I do have a directory full of profile and other .xml files, and I just don't know what to pick - my aim is same - to be able to get rid of the Cisco Anyconnect client. It is horrible, and nagging, and its integration with the OS is really bad. I'd really like to use the OS's native client if possible. Have you any idea what to look for? I know the "User group", but again - I don't know the "shared secret" or "Certificate" and how to get them

Comment: Under /opt/cisco/anyconnect, there is a file called ConfigParam.bin which seems like it should contain relevant info about the VPN configuration. But it is a binary file, and I cannot make sense of its content as shown by the xxd command.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the AnyConnect client can be used to connect to a number of different types of VPN offered by Cisco.  The process you describe above leads me to believe that you are connecting to an SSL-VPN. SSL-VPN does not require the use of a shared secret for the first layer of encryption.  Instead the client and the server auto-negotiate that first layer encryption using SSL.  You are then asked for credentials and a group membership.  The remainder of your VPN session is uniquely encrypted following Authentication.

You could script the connection so that instead of having to enter your credentials each time, you can store them in your keychain, and simply initiate the connection from the shell, or other script.  I did so a few years ago here:  http://www.wellingtonnet.net/code/2014-02-04/cisco_anyconnect_client_mac.html

I have noticed that with each update of AnyConnect, I have had to tweak this script, so use it as an example and go from there.  It has been about a year since I last needed to connect via AnyConnect.

Comment: I was actually most interested because I was hoping to configure a connection using only the native macOS VPN implementation, and not have to install or run AnyConnect at all. But thanks for the input.

Comment: @jrk same, and also TheWellington your like is dead